# Need help identifying my frost free outdoor faucet

Tags: plumbing

I have leaky weep holes so it is my understanding that I need to replace the washer on the valve assembly on the end of the stem assembly.  The screw at the end of the valve assembly on the end of the stem assembly is stuck. I can’t find the proper replacement washer but even if I could I can’t get it on since the screw won’t release.  So I need to replace the whole stem but need to know who the manufacturer is but it isn’t marked. If anyone can help I’d sure appreciate it.  I don’t have access in my house  to replace the whole faucet without tearing up the place.
 [image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to suggest the brand is ProChannel. The knurled brass cap is quite unique and I’d not seen one like that

Example that looks very similar:
[image: sillcock]

Answer (score 0):

Only manufacturers I know that make wall hydrants and Nibco and Watts. Other wise replace the wall hydrant itself.